# Four nodes with a width of 25% don't fit next to each other?

Tags: css

I have a header node in which four child nodes reside.
None have borders, padding nor margins.
All four of them have the width:25%; css rule.
In Opera it works just fine, in IE the last block flips to the next line sometimes depending on the width of the window.

I can solve it by giving one block a width of 24.8%, but Opera interprets that as 24% and thus leaves a wide open gap of 1% at the end of the blocks.

How can I solve this? It would be ok for the last block to miss a pixel on the right.

Answer (score 8):

http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/

This is a well-known issue in the CSS world, unfortunately. Likely the issue is that the 100% pixel-equivalent these fit into is an odd number, so there is a rounding error when calculating pixels.

Usually I solve this by using an IE-specific selector for . Rob suggests browser-specific stylesheets, but I always found that behavior hard to maintain, and it requires an additional HTTP load from a browser. I do also hate CSS hacks, but you can try the famous #width:24.9% after declaring the proper width  (e.g.  width:25%; #width:24.9%; ). Hopefully if IE fixes this hack in future versions, it's also along with the rounding issue.

Also, if you know the pixel width of the parent element, you could just make sure it's evenly divisible by 4. But if this is a fluid layout, that's not an option.

Comment: Thanks, I indeed found some material documenting the issue. And it seems there are no real solutions to it yet :s
Also the fact that Opera ignores fractional percentages makes it even harder. I love my opera, but this really sucks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to just load a different stylesheet depending on the browser.  You can do this with some JavaScript in the header.

Comment: I find it a sad trend that sites start requiring JS for trivial things. I can conditionally load them without JS though. It's indeed a solution. Not the best, but could do as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the rounding algorithm in use. If you have a number of pixels evenly divisible by 4, then you won't have an issue because there's no rounding issue. If you don't have that then sometimes you're going to end up with too many pixels because the widths are being rounded up.

```
total width: 800
25% width: 200
four 25% blocks: 800
```

```
total width: 799
25% width: 199.75
four side-by-side blocks: either 796 or 800
```

800 width against a 799 width window is going to drop down.

Comment: The whole idea of the percentages is fluid layouts. So caping my width would make the percentages redundant.